Blender 4.1: background image: not visible
So ...
I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PoEVlObMv0
I opened a brand new project to try it, since in my previous project I got troubles.
nothing ... I'm not able to get the JPG as background.
Where do I wrong? Here below, inthe animated GIF, what I'm doing.


Hello ! You just missed what the tutor did at 6-7 seconds which is going into camera view mode. See the answer

@Gorgious even this: it's not clear to me form the video. he gave it for granted that "everybody knows" but it's not the case. "Kid with glasses" answered and helped on this.

The background image is only available when the viewpoint is the camera. To view the background image you can either push [0] on the number pad, or you can click on View - Viewpoint - Camera. Also, please note that the background image is supposed to be more of a reference image for modeling, painting, etc. See Blender Background Image Documentation.
You can add a reference image that is viewable outside of the camera by pushing on the Add button, selecting Image, and selecting the type of image import you would like. Unless you have the "Import images as planes" addon selected, the image types in the menu will only be viewable in the viewport, and not the render.
If you wish to have an image as the actual background in the render, make (or go to) the shading window. From there select World from the top left of the Shading tab. It is in the "Shader Type" drop-down. Delete the Background node and make a new "Environment Texture" node. In that node, select your image with the Open button. That should apply it as an HDRI (a panoramic image often used for 360 degree lighting). It will only be viewable in the viewport when you switch to Rendered view, or you switch to Material view.  If you chose material view, click on the down arrow next to the render view options and select Scene World under the Lighting category.

Great for the camera.. By pressing 0 indeed I got it. Thank you
But for the World option: there I have the same effect: no image. I tried different sizes, format but nothing.

Ah, sorry about that. I'll update my answer.
